# Loop through object to take values from HTML paste clip and update form input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to parse booking details from a 3rd party website to aid completing booking form on our local system.

So I intend to copy the booking details from the 3rd party site, and paste into a textarea and then have some client side scripting pull the relevant data out and populate our form.

I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eh8eq9e4/5/

So I am having trouble with this line in the JS:

```
$.each(bookingComTargets, function(key, target) {
    $("." + target).val(text("#" + jey).html());
});
```

its supposed to pull the value from the pasted data (Which is now in div id "out") and then update the input value accordingly.

Some pitfalls:

The pasted HTML only offers classes, in most cases this is fine as I can get the required data, but I will need to loop again through the address lines as there are multiples.

In the JS section in the fiddle you will find commented an example of the paste clip

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eh8eq9e4/6/)**.

You've two typos in the posted code, first the `jey` is undefined it should be `key` :

```
("#" + jey).html()
_______^
```

Should be :

```
("#" + key).html()
```

Second one you should replace `text` by `$` :

```
text("#" + key).html()
^^^^
```

Should be :

```
$("#" + key).html()
```

Full code :

```
$.each(bookingComTargets, function(key, target) {
    $("." + target).val($("#" + key).html());
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var bookingComTargets = {
  name: "reservation-guest-name",
  email: "js-guest-email",
  address: "info-booking-address",
  telephone: "info-booking-phone"
};

$("textarea").on("input propertychange", function() {
  $("#out").html($("textarea").val());

  $.each(bookingComTargets, function(key, target) {
    $("." + target).val($("#" + key).html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input name="telephone" id="telephone" placeholder="tel" />
  <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" />
</div>
<div>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for spotting the typos. I have updated my code, and run your snippet, but its still not putting the extracted data into the form fields. Any Ideas?

Comment: adding an alert
    alert(target + " - " + $("." + key).html());

shows $("." + key).html() as undefined, so its not finding it still. Im stumped.

Comment: AHA! http://jsfiddle.net/eh8eq9e4/7/ got it. I had key and target mixed up. Switched it round and works a charm! Thanks @Zakaria for your help.